# Schema Builder length of an integer

Tags: laravel-4, database-schema

I've been searching around and the question was asked a few times, but no-one seem to be able to give a definite answer to it. How do you specify the integer length for the table column using Schema?

I've seen someone suggesting:

```
$table->integer('post')->length(11);
```

But that doesn't work - at least with Laravel 4.2 - it still produces the column as `int(10)`.

Is there a built in method to specify the integer length?

Comment: Is this by any chance related to creating foreign keys between tables?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, you can't specify the length of an integer column. You can only choose between one of the available integer types, described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html.

Hence, you cannot set the integer length in Laravel either.

You can only choose one of the available types described at
[Laravel 4.2 Database Migration Creating Column](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns).

Comment: But MySQL's integer length goes up to 11 - not 10, which seem to be the default one? Same for TINYINT which goes up to 4 etc.

Comment: It goes up to 11 for signed integers. For unsigned integers (and then I mean the `INT` type), it goes up to 10.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks, although it's a shame that you cannot specify the length - it could be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: Actually, you **can** specify the length of an integer column in MySQL. See the [Numeric Type Attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) of the same docs.The _length_ in this case is not the size of the data but the display width of the output.

Typically, boolean columns will be stored as `TINYINT(1)` even though the `TINYINT` can have a display width of up to 4.

Answer (score 14):

Thought I'd create an easy-to-copy-and-paste for general situations table.

Signed if you ***do*** require negative values and unsigned if you ***do not***.

```
| Type                | Eloquent (Schema Builder)                 | Min     | Max    |
| ------------------- | ----------------------------------------- | ------- | ------ |
| TINYINT (Signed)    | $table->signedTinyInteger('foo')          | -128    | 127    |
| TINYINT (Unsigned)  | $table->unsignedTinyInteger('foo')        | 0       | 255    |
| SMALLINT (Signed)   | $table->signedSmallInteger('foo')         | -32768  | 32767  |
| SMALLINT (Unsigned) | $table->unsignedSmallInteger('foo')       | 0       | 65535  |
```

For larger Integer types, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that you want to specify a length of 10 to match an increment id (when declaring foreign keys). If so then you have to use:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('some_id_reference');
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, in Laravel 5:

```
$table->addColumn('integer', 'post', ['length' => '10']); // Creates INT(10)
$table->addColumn('integer', 'post', ['length' => '10'])->unsigned(); // Creates Unsigned INT(10)
$table->unsignedInteger('post'); // Creates Unsigned INT(10)

$table->integer('post'); // Creates INT(11)
$table->integer('post')->unsigned(); // Creates Unsigned INT(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->bigInteger('variable');
$table->integer('variable');
$table->mediumInteger('variable'); 
$table->smallInteger('variable');
$table->tinyInteger('variable');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('variable');
$table->unsignedMediumInteger('variable'); 
$table->unsignedSmallInteger('variable');  
$table->unsignedTinyInteger('variable');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

Answer (score 0):

**Table 11.1 Required Storage and Range for Integer Types Supported by MySQL**

I think it will help for you.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

yes, it is possible to change the length of a default column by using:

```
$table->string('any_text',35)->change();
```

you can also make it nullable by using:

```
$table->string('any_text',35)->nullable()->change();
```

I hope it works for you :)

Comment: The question was about integer column, not string.