# failed migration database with laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

if the code like this : `$table->integer('no', 3);`, it's failed

if the code like this : `$table->integer('no');`, it's success

why when I use lenth, it failed to migrate db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`integer()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Schema/Blueprint.php#L510) second parameter is `$autoIncrement` which accepts `true` or `false`. You can't pass `3`:

```
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
```

Comment: so conclusions can not use a length?

Comment: Yep. If you're looking for smaller integers, check out `tinyInteger` and `smallInteger` types.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the length of an integer column, if that is what you are trying to accomplish. See this answer here for a full explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/25772960/7202919

Comment: I had see it. The link says it can not using length