# Laravel Migration is auto-incrementing all numeric columns. Why is this?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Hello I am currently trying to set up a migration in Laravel and am running into the issue to that all of my numeric columns are being set to autoincrement.

**Test Migration**:

```
Schema::create('sublobbies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->tinyInteger('sub', 2)->default(1);
    $table->tinyInteger('anothertable', 2)->default(1);
    $table->tinyInteger('anothertable2', 2)->default(1);
});
```

Besides the fact, that I am getting an `Invalid default value` error (im assuming due to the auto increments), I noticed that everything is being set to auto increment:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default val  
  ue for 'sub' (SQL: create table `sublobbies` (`id` int unsigned not null au  
  to_increment primary key, `sub` tinyint not null default '1' auto_increment  
   primary key, `anothertable` tinyint not null default '1' auto_increment pr  
  imary key, `anothertable2` tinyint not null default '1' auto_increment prim  
  ary key) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
```

Is this the natural behavior of Migrations or am I just missing something? How do I turn auto_increment off?

Comment: Laravel doesn't support specifying lengths of integer fields because many databases don't utilize it.  MySQL, for instance, only uses integer lengths as a read length.  It will store `100` in a TINYINT(1).

Comment: @Devon Oh okay, I see!

Answer (score 6):

```
Schema::create('sublobbies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->tinyInteger('sub', 2)->default(1); // remove the , 2
    $table->tinyInteger('anothertable', 2)->default(1); // remove the , 2
    $table->tinyInteger('anothertable2', 2)->default(1); // remove the , 2
});
```

the second spot in the tinyInteger() function is a boolean you are setting to true should just be

```
Schema::create('sublobbies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->tinyInteger('sub')->default(1);
    $table->tinyInteger('anothertable')->default(1); 
    $table->tinyInteger('anothertable2')->default(1);
});
```

Adding this for reference:

> tinyInteger(string $column, bool $autoIncrement = false, bool $unsigned = false)

https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_tinyInteger

Comment: So how do I specify a length like on the strings?

Comment: You don't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772759/schema-builder-length-of-an-integer